# How do I drop the None line in a csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

For example, I have the following csv dataset:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[3,5,2,5]
[,3,2,4]
```

As you can see in the dataset above, there is a list with None values.

In the above situation, I want to drop the list with None values in csv.

When I tried, I could not even try to erase it because I could not read an empty value.

Please suggest a way to erase it.

here is my tried.

-before i put in xlsx data to variable named data.

```
while k < cols:
    if data[i] != None:
        with open('data.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(data)
        f.close()
```

Comment: What format is that dataset in? Is that what the file looks like?  Does the file have those brackets?  Please create a [mcve]

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Show what you have tried. Besides being unclear what you are asking, there is no really specific problem statement.

Comment: What modules are you using? I suggest using pandas for csv. It offers a lot more versatility than just reading the file normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to remove rows with 'empty' cells, do this:

**1. Import .csv to pandas dataframe**

```
import pandas as pd

df_csv = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')
```

**2. Drop NaN rows**

```
df_csv.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any', inplace = True) 
# axis = 1 will drop the column instead of the row
# how = 'all' will only drop if all cells are NaN
```

**3. Save to .csv**

```
df_csv.to_csv('yourfile_parsed.csv', index = False)
```

**Comments**

1. It is better to refer to `None` or `NaN` rather than saying '*empty*'
2. Also, '*clear*' better called '*drop*' - people otherwise may think you want to remove all values while keeping the row

Comment: I agree with all comments to the question above. However, when my reputation was below 68, it always annoyed me tremendously that people won't simply provide the answer if they know it already rather than trying to improve my question. We all started from somewhere.